# Why is speech recognition difficult?

Tags: algorithm, theory, speech-recognition

Why is speech recognition so difficult? What are the *specific* challenges involved? I've read through a [question on speech recognition](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1102910/why-isnt-speech-recognition-advancing), which did partially answer some of my questions, but the answers were largely anecdotal rather than technical. It also still didn't really answer why we still can't just throw more hardware at the problem.

I've seen tools that perform automated noise reduction using neural nets and ambient FFT analysis with excellent results, so I can't see a reason why we're still struggling with noise except in difficult scenarios like ludicrously loud background noise or multiple speech sources.

Beyond this, isn't it just a case of using very large, complex, well-trained neural nets to do the processing, then throwing hardware at it to make it work fast enough?

I understand that strong accents are a problem and that we all have our colloquialisms, but these recognition engines still get basic things wrong when the person is speaking in a slow and clear American or British accent.

So, what's the deal? What *technical* problems are there that make it still so difficult for a computer to understand me?

Comment: To the person marking to close this as off topic / not constructive: I don't see your reasoning. I'm asking for a specific answer, not a list or subjective response. It's also a challenge that is highly embedded in the field of programming, since it is a specific programming challenge that has been around for a long time, i.e. "make some code that listens to my words and understands them". Could you explain why you have voted to close?

Comment: It isn't. Do you need to see a speech therapist? (Do they even do speech recognition?)

Comment: I haven't marked to close, but I can kind of see why others have.  It probably fits under: *this question will likely solicit opinion, debate, arguments, polling, or extended discussion.*

Comment: I don't see why there would be arguments. I'm simply asking what technical constraints cause the problem.

Comment: Could those people who voted to close (and the person who has actually voted to *delete* this question entirely) please explain themselves? I'm all for closing questions that are deemed not to be in the best interests of SO, but closing without explanation is in itself not in the best interests of SO.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Some technical reasons:

- You need lots of **tagged training data**, which can be difficult to acquire once you take into account all the different accents, sounds etc.
- Neural networks and similar gradient descent **algorithms don't scale that well** - just making them bigger (more layers, more nodes, more connections) doesn't guarantee that they will learn to solve your problem in a reasonable time. Scaling up machine learning to solve complex tasks is still a hard, unsolved problem.
- Many machine learning approaches **require normalised data** (e.g. a defined start point, a standard pitch, a standard speed). They don't work well once you move outside these parameters. There are techniques such as convolutional neural networks etc. to tackle these problems, but they all add complexity and require a lot of expert fine-tuning.
- **Data size** for speech can be quite large - the size of the data makes the engineering problems and computational requirements a little more challenging.
- Speech data usually needs to be **interpreted in context** for full understanding - the human brain is remarkably good at "filling in the blanks" based on understood context. Missing informations and different interpretations are filled in with the help of other modalities (like vision). Current algorithms don't "understand" context so they can't use this to help interpret the speech data. This is particularly problematic because many sounds / words are ambiguous unless taken in context.

Overall, speech recognition is a complex task. Not unsolvably hard, but hard enough that you shouldn't expect any sudden miracles and it will certainly keep many reasearchers busy for many more years.....

Comment: This is the kind of info I was looking for. Very interesting. Do you have any citations I could read?

Comment: Don't have any particular references to hand, but I think a bit of Googling should help you find some detail on most of these topics. Worth noting that a lot of the issues are common to machine learning in general, not just speech.

Answer (score 2):

Humans use more than their ears when listening, they use the knowledge they
have about the speaker and the subject. Words are not arbitrarily sequenced
together, there is a grammatical structure and redundancy that humans use
to predict words not yet spoken. Furthermore, idioms and how we ’usually’
say things makes prediction even easier.

In Speech Recognition we only have the speech signal. We can of course construct a
model for the grammatical structure and use some kind of statistical model
to improve prediction, but there are still the problem of how to model world
knowledge, the knowledge of the speaker and encyclopedic knowledge. We
can, of course, not model world knowledge exhaustively, but an interesting
question is how much we actually need in the ASR to measure up to human
comprehension.

Speech is uttered in an environment of sounds, a clock ticking, a computer
humming, a radio playing somewhere down the corridor, another human
speaker in the background etc. This is usually called noise, i.e., unwanted
information in the speech signal. In Speech Recognition we have to identify and filter out
these noises from the speech signal. **Spoken language != Written language**

1: Continuous speech

2: Channel variability

3: Speaker variability

4: Speaking style

5: Speed of speech

6: Ambiguity

All this points have to be considered while building a speech recognition, That's why its a quite difficult.

-------------Refered from http://www.speech.kth.se/~rolf/gslt_papers/MarkusForsberg.pdf

Answer (score 2):

Lots of major problems in speech recognition are not directly related to the language itself:

- different people (women, men, children, elders etc.) have different voices
- sometimes the same person sounds different for example when the person has a cold
- different background noises
- everyday speech sometimes contains words from other languages (like you have the german word Kindergarden in the US/English)
- some persons not from the country itself learned the language (they usually sound different)
- some persons speak faster, others speak slower
- quality of the microphone
  etc.

Solving these things always is pretty hard... on top of that you have the language/pronounciation to take care of...

For reference see the Wikipedia article http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Speech_recognition - it has a good overview including some links and book references which are a good starting point...

From the technical POV the "audio preprocessing" is just one step in a long process... let's say the audio is "crytal clear", then several of the above mentioned aspects (like having a cold, having a mixup in languages etc.) still need to be solved.

All this means that for good speech recognition you need to have a model of the langauge(s) that is thorough enough to account for slight differences (like "ate" versus "eight") which usually involves some context-analysis (i.e. semantic and fact/world knowledge, see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Semantic%5Fgap) etc.

Since almost all relevant languages have evolved and were not designed as mathematical models you basically need to "reverse engineer" the available implicit and explicit knowlegde about a language into a model which is a big challenge IMHO.

Having worked myself with neural nets I can assure you that while they provide good results in some cases they are not "magical tools"... almost always a good neural net has been carefully designed and optimized for the specific requirement... in this context it needs both extensive experience/knowledge of languages and neural nets PLUS extensive training to achieve usable results...

Comment: Just a minor correction; on the 4th paragraph you have misspelled the "crystal clear".

Answer (score 2):

I suspect you are interested in 'countinuous' speech recognition, where the speaker speaks sentences (not single words) at normal speed.

The problem is not simply one of signal analysis, but there is a large natural language component as well. Most of us understand spoken language not by analyzing every single thing that we hear, as that would never work because each person speaks differently, phonemes are suppressed, pronunciations are different, etc. We just interpret a portion of what we hear and the rest is 'interpolated' by our brain once the context of what is being said is established. When you have no context, it is difficult to understand spoken language.

Answer (score 1):

Its been a decade since I took a language class in college, but from what I recall language can be broken up into [phonemes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Phoneme). Language processors do their best to identify these phonemes, but they are unique to every individual. Even once they are broken up they must then be reassembled into a meaningful construct.

Take this example, humans are quite capable of reading with no punctuation and no capital letters and no spaces. It takes a second, but we can do it quite readily. This is kind of what a computer has to look at when it gets a block of phonemes. However, computers are not nearly as good at parsing this data out. One of the reasons is it is difficult for computers to have context. Humans can even understand babies despite the fact that their phonemes can be completely wrong.

Even if you have all the phonemes correct, then arranging them into an order that makes sense is also difficult.